# Angular 8 - No access control allow Origin header is present on the requested resource?

Tags: angular, api, cors, cross-domain

CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

http://localhost:4200/

http://localhost:52755/

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am also facing the same problem and looking for it for quite some time.. still no answer. I already added CORs in Digital Ocean to all origin * and header * . but still same problem..

Answer (score -1):

Add these nodes to your Web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type, Accept" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="POST,GET,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1728000" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: CHECK THIS - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62232629/angular-c-sharp-response-to-preflight-request-doesnt-pass-access-control-check/62232631#62232631